# Is there a way to identify certain variables in an array using a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I have to develop code that reads through each option in an array while counting the vowels and consonants in each option. This also needs to be printed in the console.

```
let vowels = 0;
let consonants = 0;
const fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Peach", "Strawberry", "Cherry", "Acai"];

for (let fruit in fruits) {
    console.log(fruits[fruit]);
    if (fruits[fruit] == "a" || fruits[fruit] == "e" || fruits[fruit] == "i" || fruits[fruit] == "o" || fruits[fruit] == "u") {
        vowels + 1;
    }
    else {
        consonants + 1;
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far, can someone explain to me what I am missing?
Once I ran it in Visual Studio Code, the console still showed all the options in the array without registering if the variable's Vowels or Consonants were even being addressed or increased:

Edit: I need to count each word in the array and display how many vowels and consonants are in each word.

```
[Running] node "d:\coding.js"
Apple
Orange
Pear
Peach
Strawberry
Cherry
Acai

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.128 seconds
```

Comment: *"without registering if the varibles Vowels or Consonants were even being addressed or increased"* - Where do you ever observe or output `vowels` or `consonants`?  Did you just forget to log those values to the console?  (As an aside... If you use `for ... of` instead of `for ... in` in this case then you can just reference the value as `fruit` instead of the clunkier `fruits[fruit]`.)

Comment: Why did you expect otherwise? You `console.log` unconditionally and never look at the values of the variables you're incrementing.

Comment: Do you want to look at just one letter per word, or do you need to count every letter in every word?

Comment: `fruits[fruit] == "a"` is checking if e.g. `Apple"=="a"`. You need to instead check if each character of "apple" is "a"

Comment: @bjelli I need to count every letter in the word and console log how many vowels and consonants are in that word. Then do the same for each word in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some more console.logs to you code,
and I've used another variable `letter`.

Do you want to look at just one letter per word,
or do you need to count every letter in every word?

```
    let vowels = 0;
    let consonants = 0;
    const fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Peach", "Strawberry", "Cherry", "Acai"];
    
    for (let word of fruits) {
        console.log("working on word", word);
    
        letter = word[0];   // this is probably wrong, do you need to check EVERY letter of a word?
    
        console.log("  looking at letter", letter);
    
        if (letter == "a" || letter == "e" || letter == "i" || letter == "o" || letter == "u") {
            vowels + 1;
        }
        else {
            consonants + 1;
        }
        console.log("  up to now i found", vowels, "vowels and", consonants, "consonants");
    }
```

You wrote that you need to count
every letter, so we need another loop to go through
each letter of the current word:

```js
        let vowels = 0;
        let consonants = 0;
        const fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Peach", "Strawberry", "Cherry", "Acai"];
        
        for (let word of fruits) {
            console.log("working on word", word);
            
            for (let letter of word.split('')) {

              console.log("  looking at letter", letter);

              if (letter == "a" || letter == "e" || letter == "i" || letter == "o" || letter == "u") {
                  vowels += 1;
              }
              else {
                  consonants += 1;
              }
              console.log("  up to now i found", vowels, "vowels and", consonants, "consonants");
            
            }
        }
```

This still does not count uppercase letters. But I'm confident
you can fix this.

Comment: "working on word Apple
  looking at letter Apple
  up to now i found 0 vowels and 0 consonants" seems wrong as an output

Comment: yes exactly. OP needs to decide if they want to handle individual letters and how....

Comment: I need to count each letter in each word and console log how many vowels and consonants are in each word as it goes down the array

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Peach", "Strawberry", "Cherry", "Acai"];

const vowels = fruits.flatMap(i=>[...i.toLowerCase()])
  .filter(c=>'aeiou'.includes(c)).length;

const consonants = fruits.join('').length - vowels;

console.log(vowels, consonants)
```

or using regex, thanks to Dave's comment below:

```js
const fruitsString = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Peach", "Strawberry", 
  "Cherry", "Acai"].join('')

const vowels = fruitsString.match(/[aeiou]/ig).length

const consonants = fruitsString.length - vowels

console.log(vowels, consonants)
```

Comment: (There... are... 15... vowels... https://giphy.com/gifs/69rOXF4YTDVDD6cwkt) When FP is your hammer everything looks like a thumb.

Comment: @DaveNewton Note: an earlier edit forgot to do `.toLowerCase()`, which I think is what you were referring to. I think you'd prefer the regex approach. I use regex a loss less frequently in regular programming, which is why I default to this approach

Comment: `fruits.join('').toLowerCase().match(/[aeiou]/g).length` Obviously the runtime matters, but superficial benchmarking has the regex version being noticeably faster.

Comment: @DaveNewton or just use `/ig` in the regex :)

Comment: Converting them once should be incrementally faster than additional work in the regex engine, but again, runtime would matter a lot.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think maybe I was just too influenced by the "use regex to solve the problem, now you have two problems..." quote, and I'm not using it enough in simple cases

Comment: It's not  so much that "regex good here" (feels icky) rather ""some FP does extra and/or redundant work"" and "regex engines get a lot of attention".

Comment: (FWIW I did simplistic benching at jsbench.me and `//ig` is slower, w/ the caveat that I'm not testing across browsers or in Node, so :shrug:)

Comment: @DaveNewton "regex engines get a lot of attention", as in a lot of development work gets done on them for the purpose of performance optimization?

Comment: Yup; they're (generally) pretty optimized.